# Iphone tab bar icon

Tags: iphone, icons, uitabbarcontroller

I should probably be asking this on some art website, but in my iPhone app I am trying to make a center button on my tab like the one Daily booth has, but mine is coming out fuzzy.  Does anyone know how to make then clean and crisp? I used illustrator to create and save the icon as a png.

Comment: Are you using a iphone 4? And the png has the good resolution ?

Comment: It should work for both retina and non-retina displays mind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the image size to 30x30 and remember to only use black and transparency. You can make this bigger for the retina display.

Also, are you saving the image as grayscale?

If you're struggling to make them yourself, why not try [glyphish.com](http://glyphish.com)?

Answer (score 0):

I really like Paint.NET on Windows for image editing, mostly because it is free.

I noticed somebody had created an Effect for Paint.NET to create tab bar icons.  I haven't tried it myself, so can't vouch for it in any way:
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Plugins/iPhone-TabbarIcon-Maker-Alpha-from-RGB-Intensity.shtml